# How can I find all `test_*` files, recursively, omitting reparse points?

Tags: windows, cmd, find

For convenience I've created links to a rather large "static" folder inside all of my `www\site1`, `www\site2`, etc. folders.

From `www\` I would like to find all files starting with `test_` in all subdirectories, without recursing into `static` for all sites.

I have gnuwin32 installed, which includes GNU find version 4.2.20, but its symlink options don't seem aware of Windows junctions ("symlinks" created with `mklink /j source target`). The closest I've gotten is:

```
find . -path "*static*" -prune -o -type f -name "test_*"
```

which sort of works. It's a little unsatisfying since it's not very general, and it also returns all the `static` folders (but not their contents).

I thought

```
dir /s /b /a:-L test_*
```

would work, but that seems to only omit the actual junctions and not their subdirectories.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Why the pruned directory still gets printed**

If you don't include an explicit action to your `find` it will imply a `-print` gets applied to the entire expression, so

```
find . -path "*static*" -prune -o -type f -name "test_*"
```

actually gets executed as

```
find . `\( \( -path "*static*" -a -prune \) -o \( -type f -name "test_*" \) \) -print
```

So if either the left side or the right side of the `exp OR exp1` is true, `find` still prints the file. If you want left side to be omitted, you can just add an explicit action to the right side

```
find . -path "*static*" -prune -o -type f -name "test_*" -print
```

**Following symlinks**

`find` does not follow symlinks by default. Try adding `-L`, though I'm not sure if this will work with windows links

> `-L`   Follow symbolic links.  When find examines or prints information about files, the information used
>          shall be taken from the properties of the file to which the link points, not from the link  itself
>          (unless  it  is  a  broken  symbolic  link or find is unable to examine the file to which the link
>          points).  Use of this option implies -noleaf.  If you later use the -P option, -noleaf will  still
>          be  in effect.  If -L is in effect and find discovers a symbolic link to a subdirectory during its
>          search, the subdirectory pointed to by the symbolic link will be searched.
>
> When the -L option is in effect, the -type predicate will always match against  the  type  of  the
>          file  that  a  symbolic  link  points  to rather than the link itself (unless the symbolic link is
>          broken).  Using -L causes the -lname and -ilname predicates always to return false.

Comment: `find` follows junction points on Windows, and the `-P` option does not prevent this (i.e. `find -P . -name "test_*" -print` traverses into linked directories).